# Structural induction proof

Tags: programming-languages

I need to prove the following:

```
reverse(append(zs, z)) = Cons(z, reverse(zs))
```

Where:

```
sealed abstract class IntList
case object Nil extends IntList
case class Cons(x: Int, xs: IntList) extends IntList

def append(xs: IntList, x: Int): IntList = xs match {
    case Nil => Cons(x, Nil)
    case Cons(y, ys) => Cons(y, append(ys, x))
} 

def reverse(xs: IntList): IntList = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case Cons(x, ys) => append(reverse(ys), x)
}
```

I've already made the induction basis:

Assume $zs=Nil$.
\begin{align*}
  reverse(append(zs, z)) &=reverse(append(Nil,z)) \\
                       &=reverse(Cons(z,Nil)) \\
                       &=append(reverse(Cons(Nil),z)) \\
                       &=Cons(z,reverse(Nil))
\end{align*}

How do I make the induction step?

Comment: In the same way – you use the definitions and everything works out.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you elaborate? I can't see how to do it!

Comment: Take $zs=Cons(w,ws)$, use the definitions of $append$ and $reverse$, and at some point you will need to use the inductive hypothesis as well.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If I start with the inner `append` I get infinite `appends`. Can you show me the first steps?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can't see how to proceed after I get: $reverse(Cons(y,append(ys,z)))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete proof:

reverse(append(Cons(w,ws),z)) =
reverse(Cons(w,append(ws,z))) =
append(reverse(append(ws,z)),w) =
append(Cons(z,reverse(ws)),w) =
Cons(z,append(reverse(ws),w)) =
Cons(z,reverse(Cons(w,ws)))

At one point we used the inductive hypothesis.